# Best way to index a tree

Tags: c, data-structures

I have a tree with number of nodes ranging from 100 to more than 500,000. Every node in the tree is given a unique id. With huge number of nodes in the tree, it is computationally heavy to parse to the tree to search for a node in it. So I thought of implementing a index data structure having the id and another pointer pointing to the node, **What is a best way to implement this indexing data structure,** I thought doing it using an array, but it won't help as the number of nodes is not known prior to the execution.

Number of nodes in the tree might be way more than 500K and it increases dynamically, The nodes in the tree are not related based on the unique id, this id is used to differentiate with other nodes and mostly used for searching the node in the tree.

Following example might give rough idea about the tree (but this is not the actual scenario, just using this to explain the tree).

> Assume the tree is describing vehicles, each node under the root node
>   classifies the type of vehicle, lets say two wheelers, trains, four
>   wheelers, trucks etc. under this nodes there might be further
>   classifications based on other criteria like make, model, engine etc..
>   and each node will have few attributes(like in xml). So at the end we
>   will be using the id to search if the node exists if so read those
>   attributes, there are multiple other functions done on the tree,
>   searching is one among them, and it consuming huge amount of time.

Comment: Can you define the nature of the ID ?

Comment: id is an integer, this is used only to differentiate one node with another, This is incremented when a new node is added.

Comment: A Chained hash could be used IMO.. In Chained hash case, you can select KEY as a common key to an ID range [Ex- ID 0 to 1000 in one chained linked list]..

Comment: btw Are nodes creted dynamically ? i mean do you know how many nodes you have before you add them to desired data structure ?

Comment: If data is not dynamic you can simply use ID as array index since you say ID is an integer you increment.

Comment: Nodes are created dynamically. When you say chained hash, do you mean to create an array of structure with size thousand, and the linked list is used for pointing to the array of next thousand and so on..

Comment: How many bytes does a node require?

Comment: For balanced search tree, it is not a heavy job to search or insert in a tree of large number of nodes. It is possible to change your data structure to AVL-tree or R-B tree?

Comment: @Throwback1986 Size of each node varies, it varies from 100bytes to 1KB.

Comment: @QmickZh The tree cannot be balanced, Nodes are linked to their parent node based on criteria.

Comment: @Naks tell me more about criteria :) That's the point you can use HashTable with linked list.. Do you have a limited number of criteria for nodes

Comment: Is 500K nodes a solid maximum?

Comment: @Throwback1986 no 500K is not solid maximum, it might grow even more than that.

Comment: @KcDoD Problem is criteria is different for different nodes, I will try generalizing it, but I am not sure if I can explain it well, for example, let us assume that the tree is of vehicles, each node below the parent not determines the vehicle type (like Two wheelers, Four Wheelers, Trains, etc) and for every node there might be other nodes determining type of wheel or engine or other characteristics. **This is not the actual scenario, I have just tried to explain using this**

Comment: Just use an array of (fixed size) tree nodes: the index is your unique(and meaningless)  id. Dont use pointers; only indexes (these are stable on realloc()) ; Use `(uint32_t)-1` (or some other impossible index value) as a sentinel value instead of a NULL pointer.

Comment: Why can't you just use a dynamic array?

Comment: @joop realloc phase is slow, but it helps the computation of index, thought of reallocating the with twice the previously allocated space, but I might end up using more space, considering the node count might shoot to more than 500K

Comment: @Naks The whole idea of using indexes instead of pointers is that the structure remains valid even after realloc. It even works for disk files or mmap()ped disk files.

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of tree nodes can't be estimated, you can use another balanced search tree, for example R-B tree, to store the address to your tree nodes.

For example, define the node structure of the balanced search tree like this:

```
struct rb_node
{
    int id;
    node *n; //pointer to your tree node
};
```

Then build a balanced search tree according to `id`.

Every time you insert a node to your tree, insert a node to the balanced tree too. Then you can find the node quickly using `id`.

Comment: Since the balancing needs to be done every time you insert a node, won't it be a overhead? I have thought of this before, but what I found was, this helps us, when you build a tree, balance it, and search it (searching done multiple times, but tree is build once), but I need to search for the node while building the tree, and balancing it now and then causes overhead. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Since you know the id and another pointer pointing to the node, the only overhead is building a balanced search tree and can be ignored.

Comment: Won't we need to balance the tree more than once?, how will you determine when to balance it?, What is the time complexity for balancing? I doubt if the overhead of balancing the search tree can be ignored.

Comment: Balancing is a part of insertion/deletion of balanced search tree and take only constant time, that is O(1). Compare to O(log n), the time complexity of insertion/deletion, it can be simply ignored.

Comment: @Naks The effective overhead of balancing depends on the frequency of nodes adding and removing relative to nodes' search. If you build the whole tree, then mainly search it, build the indexing tree in one step instead of incrementally. If you search multiple times for one or a few nodes, use adaptive index tree, say a weighted tree or a splay tree.

Comment: The tree structure heavily depends upon the order of insertion/deletion nodes. The worst case - linear complexity - is achieved on fully ordered set. Balancing tree is the way to cope with such situations. If you really believe that your data is "random-looking", you may neglect the tree-balancing completely. BTW. Tree-balancing is fast, but a little tedious procedure.

Comment: @QmickZh Will take a look at balancing the indexing tree. Will update you.

Comment: @CiaPan Since, I need the indexing tree, while building tree (building the tree and searching will happen simultaneously) I can't build the indexing tree in one step.  Searching multiple time for one or few nodes can't be predicted.

Comment: @Naks there is no need to build index tree in one step. It can grow as your tree grow. it's *dynamic*.

Comment: @QmickZh The index tree grows along with the other tree, it is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying with having an `id` field and then a `node` pointer field associated with that sounds to me something like a **hashmap** (or **hashtable**, or what have you).

If you don't know what this is, you basically have an array that can only get bigger (by powers of 2), populated with nodes.  When you want to add data, you perform a *hashing* calculation on the key, which, in this case, is the `id` field.  This gives you some number.  Then you say `number % size_of_array`.  This takes the modular remainder to get an array element that is actually within the size of the array.  Assuming that your array size is some power of two, you can ensure that all nodes are filled.

There are a number of other functions you would need, you can read about them somewhere.

Now, (or assuming you already know about hashmaps) you use your `id` field as the **key** for each node, and the **value** pointer for each node would be a pointer to the tree node.  This is usually reasonably quick, except when you have lots of *collisions*, or nodes that have the same hash, although, usually, you shouldn't have to rehash more than two or three times.

```
struct hashnode {
  void *key;  //This is the id field.
  void *value;  //This points to the tree node.
}

struct hashmap {
  uint32_t size;
  uint32_t used;

  hashnode *nodes;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this is same as the chained hash as KcDoD is suggesting. As of now, I am thinking this as my last resort